# Program runs through compiler but not giving answers(C++ Classes)

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ OOP and I find difficulties in implementing the following task:
The program is about taking information from a file, storing it in vector pointers and then printing it, but it gives proccess failure. 
Basically doesn't call the second constructor in class Car and I don't seem to find a way to fix this issue.
Would like to get some tips.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Person{
protected:
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Person(string n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
    }
    void IncAge(){
        age++;
    }
    string get_name() {
        return name;
    }
    int get_age() {
        return age;
    }

};

class Car{
public:
    string brand;
    Person* owner;
    Person* driver;
    Car(string b, Person* o, Person* d){
        brand = b;
        owner = o;
        driver = d;
        cout << "Constructor 2 called" << endl;
    }
    string get_brand(){ return brand; }
    void get_owner(){ cout << owner;  }
    void get_driver(){ cout << driver; }


};

void printall(vector<Car*> car){
    for(int i =0; i < car.size(); i++){
        cout << car[i]->get_brand();
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<Person*> people;
    vector<Car*> cars;

    ifstream openFile;
    string filename = "input.txt";
    openFile.open(filename.c_str());

    if(openFile.fail()){
        cout << "Failed opening targeted file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        int n;
        int read_age;
        string read_name, read_car, read_owner,read_driver;
        openFile >> n;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            openFile >> read_name;
            openFile >> read_age;
            people[i] = new Person(read_name, read_age);

        }

        openFile >> n;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            openFile >> read_car;
            openFile >> read_owner;
            openFile >> read_driver;

            unsigned int j = 0;
            unsigned int k = 0;
            for(; j < people.size(); j++){
                if(read_owner == people[j]->get_name()) break;
            }
            for(; k < people.size(); k++){
                if(read_driver == people[k]->get_name()) break;
            }

            cars[i] = new Car(read_car, people[j], people[k]);

        }

        openFile.close();

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
            people[i]->IncAge();
        }
        printall(cars);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your data should be private not protected or public. And you don't understand pointers. I would start again. Which C++ textbook are you learning this stuff from?

Comment: `cars[i] = new Car(read_car, people[j], people[k]);` -- You do not add items to an empty vector this way.  Where are your calls to `push_back()`, `insert()`, `emplace_back()`, etc.?  It looks like you need to go back and review the basics of how to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks PaulMcKenzie, seems to emphasize so much on that new stuff happens to blur the old simple things.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Cay Horstmann's  and Michael T. Goodrich's Data Structures and Algorithms

Comment: Never heard of it. Amazon reviews very mixed - the detailed ones say it is crap. And it is obviously overpriced, which is always a bad sign, usually meaning teachers have been bribed to recommend it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth The problem is not in the books, but in me, I'm bad in pointers because it is new stuff for me and I haven't read enough... Haven't said that I'm for first year in university, so I think those are "easy" for you mistakes to happen, but not for me.

Comment: The problem may very well be the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also learning c++, I want to comment instead of writing this as an answner, but I can't do it now.

```
people[i] = new Person(read_name, read_age);
```

use push_back() function to add person to vector

I don't think `[index]` will properly increase the size of vector and reallocate memory for new element